# Формирование структуру 6 уровней

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сохранить в базе 6 уровней такой структуры, например я самый верхний, ниже два моих рефералкой и у каждого рефералкой 2 своих? Чтобы я например проверить сколько пользователей на втором уровне? И если там не достаёт например одного вставил туда пользователя?

Comment: через дополнительно поле parent_id к примеру в базе данных

Comment: Чтобы делать произвольные выборки по деревьям, смотрите в сторону Nested Sets или Closure Tables

Comment: не понятно, идет заполнение слева направо, а если я во 3 уровне 2-й слева и хочу запустить свои 6 уровней вниз, как это оформлять?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в проектах я видел простую таблицу users

id - autoincrement primary

user_id int

parent_id int

а запросы что то вроде

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`user_id`, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
 WHERE `parent_id` = t1.`user_id` ) AS `count`
FROM `users` t1
```

Показывает у скольких пользователей в таблице такой же родитель

Что бы узнать кто записан под этим человеком

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id` = :parent_id
```

Что бы узнать соседа

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `parent_id` = (
        SELECT `parent_id` 
        FROM `users` 
        WHERE `user_id` = :user_id
) AND `user_id` != :user_id
```

Кто на вершине?

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id` IS NULL OR `parent_id` = 0
```

Comment: а как узнать сколько человек в 3 ветке?

Comment: Во первых в реляционных базах данных нет инструментов позволяющих делать рекурсивные запросы, она предназначена для хранения и быстрой выборке, поэтому на php вам надо будет построить рекурсивно многоуровневый массив, остановившись там где вам нужно, и сделать функцию подсчета количества на последнем уровне

Comment: а если например берем эту структуру, новый пользователь регистрируется, и например в 8 уровне есть одно свободное место, его тоже рекурсивно вычислять и потом туда записывать пользователя?

Comment: чтобы не нагружать систему вы можете перестраивать дерево лишь при удалении пользователя, можете вводить еще одно поле в таблице - lvl int для быстрых запросов

Comment: получается просто, что у каждого пользователя свои 6 уровней пользователей в низ и вот как это все организовать не могу понять

Comment: таких примеров море https://phpdes.com/php/postroenie-dereva-kategorijj-na-php-rekursiya/